# Does community user remove questions with upvoted/accepted answers?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, accepted-answer, upvotes, community-user

During the past few days my reputation "suddenly" went down by about 120 points, and it was due to questions removed by the community, each having an upvoted and/or accepted answer (from my side). One question has been answered almost a year ago, another was just one day old. I thought that questions with upvoted / accepted answers are never deleted by the community user. Do I remember this wrong, or did some rules change?

I'm aware of what happens when a user was removed or when users vote to close a question. But for some questions (e.g. the "Error abort trap 6"-question) none of these two reasons seem to apply, or at least the reason does not show up as such in the reputation page. For another question, in contrast, this reason is given on the reputation page (see screenshot):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All posts were correctly deleted, see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for the what posts are deleted when. Your answers were deleted because the *question* they were posted to were deleted.

One question was deleted by community votes (so not the Community User, but members of the site with enough reputation to vote to delete):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588933/c-c-vs-assemply-language

From the FAQ on deletion:

> Users with reputation ≥ 20k (more precisely, the trusted-user privilege; 4k on beta sites) are not subject to the 48-hour waiting period for deleting closed questions with a score of −3 or lower.

The other two questions were deleted by the system when the user account that posted the question was deleted:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453427/trying-to-figure-out-how-to-combine-two-tables-with-specific-values-in-sql
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583211/error-abort-trap-6

In this case the questions were deleted automatically because they had a negative score; answer scores or accepted status does not matter in this process.  One account was deleted by a moderator as a sock puppet, the other self-deleted.

Quoting the FAQ again:

> The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a negative score when its owner’s account is deleted.

This is the risk of answering questions with a negative score.

Note that the *User was removed* entry is independent from the posts deletions. A user that voted for one of your answer was deleted, and their votes were removed from the system. That that vote was by one of the users that posted a now-deleted question is neither here nor there.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But at least for one question the reason "user was removed" does not shine up (see edited question)

Comment: @StephanLechner: you *also* lost a vote cast by one of the deleted users. That entry you see is for the vote, not for the post deletion.

Comment: Ah -  OK. It seems that user "user9030105" having posted "error-abort-trap-6"-question was deleted  (I can't find him on the users tab). I thought that in this case the "user was removed" would appear next to this question on the rep-tab, but this assumption seems to be wrong. Thanks for clarification!